# How to Access buttons and labels of one mxml file from another mxml file

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flashbuilder4

I m completely fresher in Flex Programming,
 I have a FileUploadPanel.mxml which contains functionality of uploading, deleting and viewing one file only.. Now i need to modify the application to accommodate multiple attachments facility, So i created another panel ie MultiFileUpload.mxml, which has the functionality to get all attachment in form of List of Objects , and for each object-id I need to call the previous File Upload Panel, Every Thing is Working fine, but when i am accessing buttons and Labels of FileUpload.mxml it is throwing error:

```
1009- cannot access property and method of null object reference. 

code FileUploadPanel.mxml



 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="492" height="46" >
        <mx:Label x="0" y="4" text="File Attachment:"/>
        <mx:Button x="93.5" y="2" label="Browse" id="btnBrowseView" click="__onBrowse();" enabled="true" width="67"/>
        <mx:Text x="264.5" y="4" width="100%" id="lbUploadFile" height="18 " />
        <mx:Button x="165" y="2" label="Upload" id="btnUpload" enabled="true" click="reserveAttachment();" width="67"/>
        <mx:Text x="10" y="25" width="100%" height="18" id="__status__" fontWeight="bold" color="#023AF1"/>
        <mx:Script>
            <![CDATA[


         public function SetAttachmentID(anAttachmentID: Number): void
            {               
                this.AttachmentID = anAttachmentID;
                lbUploadFile.text = "";  //here i am getting error
                __status__.text = "";
                if (AttachmentID != -1)
                {
                    m_data = new DocumentsAdt();
                    m_data.ConnectionIndex = ConnectionIndex;
                    m_data.OnLoadData = this.OnDoxLoaded;
                    m_data.LoadFromWebService(AttachmentID);

                    btnBrowseView.label = "View";
                    btnUpload.label = "Delete";
                    btnUpload.enabled = true;
                    btnUpload.visible = true;
                }
                else
                {   
                    btnBrowseView.label = "Browse";
                    btnUpload.visible = false;
                    btnUpload.label = "Upload";
                    btnUpload.enabled = false;
                    Init();
                }
            }
           </mx:Script>
</mx:Canvas>
```

Code MuliFileUpload.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="400" height="300" xmlns:BoycePanels="BoycePanels.*" xmlns:ns1="com.flextoolbox.controls.*" xmlns:ns2="com.adobe.flex.extras.controls.*" xmlns:ns3="BoycePanels.*">



    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[



            import Adt.Attachments.DocumentsAdt;

            import com.boycepensions.DocumentsService.DocumentsService;
            import com.boycepensions.DocumentsService.GetDocumentsRecordResultEvent;

            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            private var m_data: DocumentsAdt = null;
            import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
            import BoycePanels.FileUploadPanel;
            import mx.controls.Alert;

            public var ConnectionIndex: int = new int(0);
            public var AttachmentID: Number = new Number(-1);
            public var acDocList:ArrayCollection=null;
            public function Init():void
            {
                getDocs_Test();
            }

            public function getDocs_Test():void    
            {
                blah..blah..blah..
            }
            public function OnGetDocumentsRecord(event:GetDocumentsRecordResultEvent): void   
            {
               var  acDocList:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection();
                var m_data:DocumentsAdt=new DocumentsAdt();
                if (!CheckResult(event.result))         
                    return;         
                else
                {
                    acDocList=m_data.LoadDocumentsFromXML(event.result);          
                    for each(var obj:DocumentsAdt in acDocList)
                    {
                        var pnl:FileUploadPanel=new FileUploadPanel();
                        //pnl.OnReserveAttachmentDone=OnReserveAttachment;
                        pnl.Init();
                        pnl.SetAttachmentID(obj.Document_ID); //here it is throwing error
                    }
                }

            }
```

Please suggest, i have already spent days and hours on it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to access lbUploadFile when it hasn't been initialized. So if you want the FileUploadPanel show on Stage, try add it to stage before call SetAttachmentID function, like this.

```
var pnl:FileUploadPanel=new FileUploadPanel();
this.addChild(pnl);//add it to where you want
```

If the pnl needn't show on stage, remove the lines where access the children.